# Python matrix, any solution?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, sum

MY input(just for example):

```
from numpy import * 

x=[['1' '7']
 ['1.5' '8']
 ['2' '5.5']
 ['2' '9']]
```

I want to make next thing on **random matrix**:

**1. for each row calculate:**

```
> for example first row:    [1;7]*[1,7] = [[1,  7];      #value * value.transpose
                                          [7,  49]]

> for example second row:   [1.5;8]*[1.5,8]=  [[2.25, 12];
                                               [12,  64]]
 >.......
```

This is simple with **numpy**, because transpose is just     `x.T`, if x=[1,7]
This must be calculated for every row on matrix!

**2. now I want to sum as in this way...**

> ```
> [1+2.25+...         7+12+......  ]
> [                                ]           
> [7+12+....          49+64+....   ]
> ```

So result is this matrix.

Any ideas?

---

### EDIT2:

```
x=[['1','7']
 ['1.5', '8']
 ['2', '5.5']
 ['2','9']]

y = x[:, :, None] * x[:, None]
print y.sum(axis=0)
```

I received error:

> "list indices must be integers, not 
>   tuple"

But if x is `x = numpy.array([[1, 7], [1.5, 8], [2, 5.5], [2, 9]])` then it's ok, but I don't have such input.

Comment: Just *add* the matrices?

Comment: Are you sure you want `x` to be an array of *strings*?

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x=np.array([[1, 7],[1.5, 8],[2, 5.5],[2, 9]])

In [3]: np.sum(np.outer(row,row) for row in x)
Out[3]: 
array([[  11.25,   48.  ],
       [  48.  ,  224.25]])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should create the matrix containing floating point numbers instead of strings:

```
x = numpy.array([[1, 7], [1.5, 8], [2, 5.5], [2, 9]])
```

Next, you can use NumPy's [broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting) to build the product matrices:

```
y = x[:, :, None] * x[:, None]
```

Finally, sum over all matrices:

```
print y.sum(axis=0)
```

printing

```
[[  11.25   48.  ]
 [  48.    224.25]]
```

Note that this solution avoids any Python loops.

Comment: Hmmm, this is perfect for me; but my input is:
x=[['1' '7']
 ['1.5' '8']
 ['2' '5.5']
 ['2' '9']]
How can implement your code for this? i try with array, but no sucess...

Comment: @thaking: Why does your matrix contain strings?  Usually, you sould initialise it in a way that you have a matrix of floating point number right from the beginning.  If this is impossible for any reason, you can convert the matrix using `x = x.astype(float)`.  (Note that I can't imagine any reason why this should be necessary.)

Comment: Please look at my EDIT 2, where I described my problem with input data...and why I can't get matrix..thanks

Comment: @thaking: This seems to be a rather unrelated question.  You might want to ask a new question for this.  Make sure that you explain where your "original input" comes from in that new question.

Comment: @thaking: As stated in my post, you should initialise your matrix as an *NumPy array of floats*, and not, as you did in the edit, as *a list of strings*.  NumPy arrays and Python lists are very different data types, and your are trying to use the same code for both of them.