# Python matrix problems

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

This is continued from this thread: [Python matrix, any solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835583/python-matrix-any-solution)

---

**Input**

```
from numpy import *
import numpy

x=[['1','7'],
 ['1.5', '8'],
 ['2', '5.5'],
 ['2','9']]
```

**Code**

```
y = x[:, :, None] * x[:, None]
print y.sum(axis=0)
```

I received error:

> "list indices must be integers, not 
>   tuple"

But if x is
 `x = numpy.array([[1, 7], [1.5, 8], [2, 5.5], [2, 9]])` then it's ok, but I don't have **such input**.

Comment: Lists are different than numpy arrays.  If you want to use numpy operations, you need to convert your lists to arrays first.

Comment: And how can I do this? I try many thing but with no sucess

Comment: in the input, you left out the commas after each row.

Comment: My problem is that I have
[['1','7']...] instead [[1,7]...]

Comment: Please don't `import * from numpy`; that will pollute your namespace with a great bunch of functions and confuse readers of your code (both humans and code analysis tools). If you want to save on typing, prefer `import numpy as np` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `x` to a numpy array of numbers:

```
x = numpy.asanyarray([[float(z) for z in y] for y in x])
```

Comment: This will not solve my problem;  My problem is that I have
[['1','7']...] instead [[1,7]...]

Comment: @ant: `map` vs. list comprehensions is a matter of style. I prefer this solution since the comprehension expression mirrors the 2d result matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

It's not 100% clear to me what you're asking/trying to achieve here.  In response to the comment about having [['1','7'] ...]:  Currently you have string elements in your list; you can easily enough convert to numeric elements with:

```
xf = [[float(el) for el in m] for m in x]
```

Original post:
Define your list by putting commas between your list elements:

```
x=[['1','7'],['1.5', '8'],['2', '5.5'],['2','9']]
```

When I didn't do this, I got your error, but by doing this I avoided the error.

Comment: Well I know that, but my input is much larger from that and is random, i cannot add commas between elements! This element's which I have is just example...

Comment: Why would you not be able to add commas?  Perhaps your problem is that you can not add commas, not that you need this to work with no commas.

Comment: My problem is that I have
[['1','7']...] instead [[1,7]...]